# Where did Heroku's interactive architecture diagram go?

Tags: heroku

Heroku used to have an interactive diagram on their home site which discussed the platform's architecture. I can't seem to find it anywhere - is it gone forever?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to write a comment yet but heroku took down a lot of those docs after the rap genius post about a year ago.  The diagram you are describing sounds like one of those most likely taken down. Here is the rap genius post: http://news.rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-annotated